# PHP variable to .sql, zip it and then download

Tags: php, mysql, download

I am generating mySQL script. Result is something like this...

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`v1`,`v2`) VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`v1`,`v2`) VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`v1`,`v2`) VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`v1`,`v2`) VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`v1`,`v2`) VALUES ('1', '2');
```

There are over 10,000 lines. I am assigning all this to a variable called $sql_dump

I then download this variable using the following script...

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=backup_export.sql");
echo $sql_dump;
```

It is working perfectly fine. However, the file is too big it can be as big as 20mb. Instead of downloading it as .sql file. I want to zip it and download it. I don't want to keep anything on server. It should generate on the fly. Just like we dump mySQL from phpmyadmin, when we choose download as zipped.

Please help thanks

Comment: See this Q&A => http://stackoverflow.com/q/21557062/ found under Related.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the php [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to compress the file with zip server function, after the sql file was generated. After that you will need to check if the [file exist](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and download it.
You will need to have a folder to store the files and a rutine to clean your server, I mean to delete all zip generated files.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the content of a string in a file using file_put_content and the create a zip of it.

```
$file = 'abc.sql';

file_put_contents($file, $sql_dump);
$z = new ZipArchive();
$z->open("sqldump.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

$current = file_get_contents($file);

$z->addFile($current);
$z->close();
```