# Codeigniter zip library downloading empty zip

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function download(){
    $this->load->library('zip');

    $path = './application';

    $this->zip->read_dir($path);

    $this->zip->download('VSSS.zip');
}
```

It downloading ZIP but inside ZIP there is no content. ZIP size is almost 800 kb but inside ZIP there is no content. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: See this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557062/create-and-download-zip-file-using-php

Comment: @MdRashedPervez But I want to add directory not content.

Comment: The issue should be with path.

Try using base_url in the path . hope its not application folder of codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try alternative way

```
$path = './application';
$file_name = 'VSSS.zip';

force_download($path.'/'.$file_name, NULL);
```

read more about codeigniter force_download

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

For those who is still struggling with this issue just remove `"/"` or `"./"` from beginning of path.